# Searching for roots of complex function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I'm searching for the roots of a complex function of $x$ with parameters $k$ and $q$
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x;q,k)&=
2 i q\log(-2 ik)+i\pi-2 i\;\text{Im}\big(\log(\Gamma(1+2 i q))\big)\\
&+\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(1+i q+i qx/k)}{\Gamma(1+iq+iqx/k)}\right)+\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{-1-x}}{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{-x-1}}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
where $k=\sqrt{(-x+1)(-x-1)}$, $x$ is complex with $\text{Re}(x)<-1$ and $\text{Im}(x)>0$ and $q$ is real and positive parameter. If I change the  seed in `FindRoot` slightly, the result changes dramatically. How may I efficiently find these roots?

Code:

```
2 I*q*Log[-2*I*Sqrt[(-x + 1) (-x - 1)]] + I*π -  2*I*Arg[
Gamma[1 + 2*I*q]] + Log[Gamma[1 + I*q - I*q*x/Sqrt[(-x + 1) (-x - 1)]]] - 
Log[Gamma[1 - I*q - I*q*x/Sqrt[(-x + 1) (-x - 1)]]] + Log[Sqrt[-x + 1] - 
Sqrt[-x - 1]] - Log[Sqrt[-x + 1] + Sqrt[-x - 1]]
```

Comment: Could you post some code? The function and the `FindRoot`?

Comment: Find the code above

Comment: What's the actual value of q?

Comment: You seem to have a highly oscillatory function near `x == -1`, for `q == 0.1, 1., 10.`.  Try plotting it (`ContourPlot[Abs[fn[x]],...]`).

Comment: You are aware that `LogGamma[]` is built-in?

Comment: values of $q$ are $>4.5$, reals.

Comment: You code given in TEX is wrong, you have Log[Gamma[1 + I q + I q x/k]/Gamma[1 + I q + I q x/k]], which is zero. The given mMathematica code differs from TEX code. What is the real code ?

Comment: @Akku14:  I edited (with approval)  the  initial latex because I felt the format was difficult to read.  I made a mistake with transcribing the log expression as you identified, however I am just now realizing the posted Matheamtica  code is significantly different than the latex I edited.    Sorry about this.  Also just realized the post is 8 years ago.    Is it possible to get a copy of the original post  I edited?

Answer (score 2):

one of the best way to finding the roots of complex functions is Davidenko's Method of Complex Root Search in this way you can find the exact root of complex functions by changing your equation into a differential equation. Here is a sample of this method you can use this way.

```
(*Davidenko's Method of Complex Root Search*)
Clear[γ]
Pm = D[P, γ];
Intv = .0045 + .0041 I;
γ = a[t] + I *b[t];
g = Re[P];
h = Im[P];
gb = Re[Pm];
ga = -Im[Pm];
Pg = (gb)^2 + (ga)^2;
tf = 20
sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == ((-gb*g + ga*h)/Pg), 
   b'[t] == ((-ga*g + gb*h)/Pg), a[0] == Re[Intv], 
   b[0] == Im[Intv]}, {b, a}, {t, 0, tf}]
Print[Plot[Evaluate[{b[t], a[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tf}]]
a[tf] /. sol
b[tf] /. sol
```

In this method P is your equation that should be equal to zero and Gamma is the variable of your equation and Intv is the initial value that you want to find the root near.

Comment: I note that you split the equation into real and imaginary parts and solve separately. Mathematica can solve complex differential equations and thus this aspect of your approach may be unnecessary. I keep the equation complex. Are there advantages in splitting the solution procedure?

Comment: Can you give a good reference for this method where I can find its description?